# Changing Date Format in Google Charts

Tags: date, charts, formatting, google-visualization

I've got a problem with changing the date tooltip when hovering over a point in my Google chart. You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5smu5ng7/15/

As you can see, the tooltips read "Feb 1, 2017". I want them to just read "February 2017", but I can't seem to get it right.

According to the Google Charts website the following segment, which i have included, should do the trick, but it doesn't:

```
      hAxis: {
         format: 'MMMM/yyyy'
      }
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

tooltips use the formatted values from the data table

use a date formatter to set the date format on the data table column

to format the first column...

```
var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMMM/yyyy'});
formatDate.format(dataTable, 0);
```